# Using C library in Numba

Tags: python, numba

I have a bunch of C libraries that perform CPU-intensive computation. I would like to use them with Numba in threaded mode to squeeze maximum performance out of the multicore system.

There are some simple examples in Numba sources:

- https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/master/examples/cffi_example.py
- https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/master/examples/ctypes_example.py

but they don't provide enough information (same as documentation) on how to interact with more complex arguments.

My libraries have declarations like:

```
int rci_smooth(int size, double *opts, double **src, double **dst);
```

I was unable to construct pointers (ctypes and FFI are very limited and don't allow pointer creation, memory allocations or casts).

So what is the Numba way of interacting with C libraries?

Comment: Examples on scalars and single pointers: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3086 (Actually this is a Cython API func, but this doesn't really matter. But how does this double pointer inputs relate to some easy Python object (Numpy array)?

Comment: These are twodimensional input and output arrays, I've tried to create a simple wrapper using a numpy array but that solution has crashed :( The only code that works as expected at the moment is `f.new("double*[]", [f.cast("double*", data.ctypes.data)]),`. Thank you for the reference I'll dig more in related issues and maybe I'll find the way.

Comment: A Numpy nd- Array is always a single pointer which points to some allocated memory (the same as in C) It seems like you are using an array of pointers which points to double arrays and not a 2d or in a general way nd-array. eg. consider a 2d c-contigous numpy array of shape (5,20). If you want to access [2,5] the equivivalent in C would be [2*20+5].